# c#, listbox, stackOverflow exception

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, selecteditemchanged

I inherited KryptonToolkit ListBox control to get SelectedItemChanging event.

```
public class CPListBox : KryptonListBox
{       
    public event CancelEventHandler SelectedIndexChanging;

    protected virtual void OnSelectedIndexChanging(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        SelectedIndexChanging(this, e);
    }

    protected override void OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
    {           
        CancelEventArgs cArgs = new CancelEventArgs();
        OnSelectedIndexChanged(cArgs);

        if(!cArgs.Cancel)
        {
            base.OnSelectedIndexChanged(e);
        }
    }
}
```

In form I handle event with code:

```
    void UsersListBoxSelectedIndexChanging(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if(_presenter.CurrentUser.IsModified)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Nie zapisales zmian!");
            e.Cancel = true;
        }

    }
```

And I got stackOverflow ;) Exception. Maybe someone now what is wron with this code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're recursively calling the method in itself forever. There's no terminating condition for these recursive calls. It'll result in Stack Overflow.

```
protected override void OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
{                       
       CancelEventArgs cArgs = new CancelEventArgs();
       OnSelectedIndexChanged(cArgs); // Clearly calling yourself indefinitely.
       //...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
protected override void OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
        {                       
                CancelEventArgs cArgs = new CancelEventArgs();
                //Next line!!
                OnSelectedIndexChanged(cArgs);

                if(!cArgs.Cancel)
                {
                        base.OnSelectedIndexChanged(e);
                }
        }
```

You're calling yourself. Hence the StackOVerflow exception.

Answer (score 2):

You have `OnSelectedIndexChanged` call within `OnSelectedIndexChanged`, it's an endless recursive call.